# Child UIViews unable to receive touch events

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` that embeds a `UITableView`. This table view is 3/4 the size of the entire screen in height. the remaining 1/4th of the `UIViewController` has a rounded `UIButton` that **triggers a new UIView** on top of the parent view. (`UITableView`).

Upon instantiating and calling a `UIView` with a background that is set to:
 `self.backgroundColor = UIColor(black: 1, alpha: 0.5)` it would normally fill the entire view with a black see-through background that will then have an additional `UIView` with the following constraints:

```
Leading: 10
Trailing: 10
Top: 50
Bottom: 50
```

this, in turn, gives me a 'Card' effect on top of the `tableView`. This 'Card' view then has a `UITextview` property that is supposed to show the keyboard when the user taps the view with the textview embedded.

**The Problem:**
Upon selecting the `UITextview`, or even touching this 'Card' view, the background table is being selected and interacted with. Neither the 'Card' textfield raises the keyboard nor does it make itself solely interactive as the parent table controller seems to be getting the touch events.

Is there any solution to this problem that is encountered in iOS 11? I never experienced this issue in iOS 10. I am using iPhone X for the further note on my issue.

**Here is an example of the actual issue occurring.**

[image]

**NOTE:** If I were to select the dark area of the card itself, the table view would receive touch events but not the text area within the card view. The reason this card view has the keyboard showing is that I called it manually in code with the `textview.becomeFirstResponder` method.

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:** I have also enabled the `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on the overall presenting child view. Still does not work and parent view receives touches only.

**Code for the Card**

```
class Card: UIView {

// instantiating the textview 
var textview = UITextview()
var cardView = UIView()


private override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(black: 1, alpha: 0.5)    
    self.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    // Just demo the textview
    self.textview.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300. height: 100)



    self.addSubview(cardView) // adding the cardView as a subview to the background colored view
    cardView.addSubview(textview)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Error")
}

private func ConstrainCardWith() {
    // Constraints 

}


}
 extension UIView {

func Width()-> CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
}
func Height()-> CGFloat{
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
}
}
```

Comment: pls add some code :)

Comment: it looks like that you are setting layer.z position

Comment: `isUserInteractionEnabled` on the child view will cause only the parent to receive touched. Bad idea..

Comment: @incmiko I was not aware of this. Prior to iOS 11, I did this as above and I never encountered any issues like this. One of my other apps has this problem. It was written for iOS 10 Swift 3. now it also has issues :(

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KEy5ueEt Works for me on iOS 11 still..

Comment: @Brandon will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The question is your container view(cardview) has no frame, so your child view(textview) can not be touch cause it is out of bounds, so just add some frame in your card view will solve this question

Comment: The cardView itself is constrained with autolayout. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @DwellingNYC When you add a view programmatically, you need to set its translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints false, otherwise, it will set its autolayout automatically. So in this situation, you added a cardview that size is 0, and then it will set the constraints become zero.